# Adding an element after another element that has no parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to implement a reusable UI element in jQuery where I add a button after an HTML element.

There are two scenarios how the element will be used: statically declared in the HTML and dynamically created in JS. I have problems implementing the second use case.

The static use case:

```
<span class=".ui-element'>Content</span>
```

I pick up the element in jQuery and put my button after the span:

```
the_span.after(the_button);
```

This works fine so far.

A problem occurs when using the same technique on a dynamically created span:

```
var the_span = $("<span>").text("Content").after(the_button);
return the_span; // caller is responsible for adding it the DOM
```

This does not work: there is no button in the DOM after this. I guess it's because the span has no parent yet, while the statically declared span has a parent?

This can be solved by

1. introducing a wrapper element around the dynamically created span:
   `var wrapper = element.wrap($('span')).parent();
   wrapper.append(the_span, the_button);`
   Now my function has to return the wrapper instead of the span, so the caller can add it to the DOM. This is unexpected behavior and breaks chaining. I also don't want to require a wrapper in the static use case, because it's not needed there.
2. `the_span.append(the_button);`
   I can't use this solution, because I want to be able to use .text() and .html() on the original span afterwards, which would remove the button.
3. require that the span has been added to the DOM before adding my button. This works, but I'd prefer a solution that works without requiring this.

How can I solve this?

Comment: "*This does not work: there is no button in the DOM after this*" - is the `<span>` added to the document after that; because I don't see in that line of jQuery where you're appending anything to the document?

Comment: use this:  var span = document.createElement("span"); var the_span = $(span).text("Content").after(the_button);

Comment: @DavidThomas the function returns the span for the caller to add it to the DOM. I have edited the question to clarify this, thanks

Comment: @Legends: I have addressed this in my question. I want to be able to use .text()/.html() on the span afterwards.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do it that meets all your restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.add` instead of `.after`, as following:

```
var the_span = $("<span>").text("Content").add(the_button);
return the_span; // caller is responsible for adding it the DOM
```

Using an `.add` will add the element to the jQuery selection.

See it in work: https://jsfiddle.net/nbm83e85/

**Update:**

You should note, that changing the text of the `the_span` instance as following:

```
the_button.text("Changed Button Name");
the_span.text("New Span Content");
```

Will change the text for all selected elements in `the_span` jQuery collection, which is the span and the button, therefor the button's text will be changed to the same value as the span.
To overcome this issue, you should use it the following way:

```
the_button.text("Changed Button Name");
$(the_span[0]).text("New Span Content");
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

about your second solution

> 2. the_span.append(the_button);
>      I can't use this solution, because I want to be able to use .text() and .html() on the original span afterwards, which would remove the button.

did you try

```
the_span.parent().append(the_button);
```

to save  benefits of .text() and .html()

Comment: Since he hasn't added `the_span` to the DOM yet, it doesn't have a parent.